# Jenkins ext-email plugin fails to send email on build success

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins version 1.480.3 installed on my machine and Email-Extension Plugin 2.28.

I have configured my jobs on Jenkins and everything works fine except the final build success email.

I have configured four triggers for Email-Extension plugin:

1. Failure
2. Success
3. Unstable
4. Before Build

For all the triggers I have enabled "Attach Log" and all works fine except the "Success".

I get the following message on screen:

> Email was triggered for: Success
>   Sending email for trigger: Success
>   Request made to compress build log
>   Sending email to: abc@example.com def@example.com
>   Error sending to the following VALID addresses: abc@example.com def@example.com
>   Notifying upstream projects of job completion
>   Capturing build context information.
>   Finished: SUCCESS

Please could someone help me since I really have no clue how to resolve this.

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem too. In the end, it was because my **attached build log was too large**! The SMTP server refused to send out the e-mail causing the error message:

```
Error sending to the following VALID addresses: ...
```

Disabling the option to attach the build log or fixing the output of my build  to not dump so much text fixed the problem:

[image]

Comment: Yes removing the attachment works but I need the attachment. Is there any global config to set the file size to attach? instead of letting it fail

Comment: @dsharew Did you find any way to have attachments as well?

Comment: I am not able to receive apk through mail......getting this : Malware was detected in one or more attachments included with this email message. 
Action: All attachments have been removed.
android-release-signed.apk

Comment: bty what if we select "Compress and Attch Build Log" will it work or it will also fail ?

Comment: @AshishKarpe as long as the compression brings the file size down enough, this could be a viable solution as well.

Comment: Same here. But an important tip: go to the jenkins general settings and in the Extended Email configuration section, select the "Debug" checkbox, then you will have a chance to see exactly what is happening. For me it was a message such as: "SendFailedException message: 552 5.3.4 Error: message file too big". Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a bug in the plugin. Here's a workaround:

In the global settings for the plugin make sure to provide a full e-mail address for *System Admin E-mail Address*, (e.g. *foo@bar.com*, not just *foo*), **even though** you've specified the *Default user E-mail suffix*. The address itself can be bogus, though.

Comment: In my case 'System Admin E-mail Address' was blank

Answer (score 4):

For Email, you have to install following plugins.

- Email-ext plugin
- Email-ext Template Plugin

To provide the configuration, go to the Jenkins System configuration page (Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > ” E-mail Notification ” section). You will be able to see the below screen to add email configurations:

```
   SMTP server name : smtp.gmail.com
   User name : user_email_id@gmail.com
   Password : user_email password
   Use SSL : Checked
   SMTP Port : 465
```

Now, configure “Extended E-mail Notification” section. You will be able to see the below screen. Fill the same value as above parameter.

Now, Click on Default triggers at bottom right corner and select success. Apply and save you configuration.

Now Goto your job and Click the Add post-build action drop-down, select E-mail notification option.

Enter the recipient email id in the ‘E-mail Notification’ box and select the checkbox next to the ‘Send e-mail for every unstable build’ option.

Click the ‘Add post-build action’ drop-down and select the ‘Editable Email Notification’ option.

In Project Recipient List , This is a comma separated list (optional whitespace after commas) of email addresses that should receive emails. May contain references to build parameters. To CC or BCC someone instead of putting them in the To list, add cc: or bcc: before the email address (e.g., cc:someone@example.com, bcc:bob@example.com).

In Attachments field, you have to give the path of your binary file (i.e path of your .ipa file like, build/artifacts/IPA-Name.ipa)

Now click on Advanced Settings at bottom right corner. Click on Add trigger and select Success trigger. Click on Add drop down from the success trigger  and select Recipient List  option. Apply and Save your configuration.

n mac-mini for iOS job configuration, if email is not send and gives you java exception error message then you must turn on  less secure apps.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, and it was because I forgot to set the SMTP server (in the plugin section of configuration), but only saw the default SMTP server settings.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that the global jenkins email configurations are not set correctly.

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> E-mail Notification

This is the default plugin, not the extended one you installed manually. The **SMTP server** field defaults to localhost, so unless you have an email server setup and running on the same box, this needs to be set.

If that is set then I would try telnet'ing to your email server from your Jenkins server to make sure there is not a connection error.

Answer (score 1):

After days of search for answer, it turns out the gmail has attachment limit for 25 mb, and my output is larger than that.

Check your output size if you met this issue and you are using gmail for mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Refer all above solutions, if it doesn't work. You can try this solution.
Zip file is blocked in Gmail. You should rename your zip file inside script before send it. (Example: file.zip.abcxyz). I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I  had the same problem. It turns out that for some reason, Jenkins would not save my "Extended E-mail Notification" SMTP settings. At one point, it did save the setting and the emails started working. Make sure that the bit in red is selected and double-check it after you press Save:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If every thing fails, try restarting jenkins process. That solved for me. Somehow the Jenkins system was unable to load all of the configs without a restart? But give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Today i faced this issue on a jenkins machine that was sending emails just fine till a couple of weeks ago. I turned it on today and it just wont send emails because of "Error sending to the following VALID addresses"

I tried these steps:

1. Made sure I am not attaching any log file in the email.
2. Made sure "System Admin" email has the domain name mentioned.
3. Jenkins was able to successfully send emails to me when i tried it by "Test configuration by sending test e-mail"
4. Downgraded my email ext plugin.

None of the above mentioned steps helped.

Finally i replaced my company's SMTP server with the jenkins default server and it worked just fine. Not sure why this has happened, I need to talk to my IT guys and see if they have enabled any new security in SMTP server.

Hope this helps to people who hit this same issue.

Thanks