# Error sending to the following VALID addresses Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I will receive emails when I trigger using build now manually, but I don't receive emails when I tried to using it in batch mode. Below is the log I obtain when triggered in batch mode.

```
Email was triggered for: Always
Sending email for trigger: Always
Sending email to: abc@example.com
Error sending to the following VALID addresses: abc@example.com
```

Note: There are no build logs attached while sending email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins ext-email plugin fails to send email on build success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191040/jenkins-ext-email-plugin-fails-to-send-email-on-build-success)

Comment: I have tried all the options mentioned in the link. But with the same configuration when manually triggered through Build Now option I receive email. When I scheduled it for some time, I am not able to receive it.

Answer (score 18):

You should set SMTP Server and Authentication in both E-mail Notification and Extended E-mail Notification sections.
Click Advanced button to see this Use SMTP Authentication section.

Comment: "You should set SMTP Server and Authentication in both E-mail Notification and Extended E-mail Notification sections. Click Advanced button to see this Use SMTP Authentication section." I have done this and tested connections it's working but not  working when build is sucess

Comment: Make sure your Job's E-mail Notification triggers is Always.@AshishKarpe

Answer (score 5):

**Error - Not sent to the following valid addresses: <valid_recipient_address> *OR* Error sending to the following VALID addresses: <valid_recipient_address>**

**Reason** - Email address of sender is not correct.

**How to troubleshoot -** Enable the debug mode from Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> (Search for Extended E-mail Notification configuration -> Check Enable Debug Mode

**Example of Working code**

```
emailext attachLog: false, 
  attachmentsPattern: 'example_file.yaml',
  from: '<valid_sender_address>',
  body: 'Test Message',
  subject: 'Test Subject',
  to: '<valid_recipient_address>'
```

Answer (score 3):

In your Jenkins configuration, make sure that you have entered correct email address for "**System Admin e-mail address**".

Notification e-mails from Jenkins will be sent with this address in the "from" header.

Answer (score 2):

For me, file size was 5-7MB, I looked at my internet speed meters, saw it, using the full upload speed for around 1 minute, but couldn't complete and gave that error message.

Then I tried smaller file, like 10KB, it worked like charm.

So, for my case, my guess is, somehow file is not getting properly uploaded to email server.

Answer (score 0):

If every thing fails, try restarting jenkins process. That solved for me. Somehow the Jenkins system was unable to load all of the configs? But give it a try.