# No attachment in Jenkins email

Tags: jenkins, automation

I want to configure Jenkins in a way that it displays an HTML file "emailable-report-new.html" in the email content and have a zip file as an attachment. But only either of them works i.e. if I only add the HTML file in the Content or send the path of the zip file in "Attachment", it is coming fine but its just that both of them are not coming together.

PFA the screenshot of my Jenkins settings.
I have tried changing the slash to "/" , "\" , "\" but it did not solve it. Also, there is no "File not found error". Please help.

**Jenkins version** - 2.126. I tried with the latest one - 2.128 but still no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUMb7.png) work for me.

1. For attachment use wildcards like `**/*.zip`
2. As in screenshoot **The base directory is the workspace**, so I recommend check Yours filepaths. Just add in Execute shell filed `ls -lR $WORKSPACE`

Comment: I tried the above method but it gives me "Error sending to the following VALID addresses: " and no email is sent.

Comment: That's another question, checkout
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283569/error-sending-to-the-following-valid-addresses-jenkins