# Jenkins: Can't send zip archive via email

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-email-ext

I want to fetch project source code from GitLab, archive it and send it via email.

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
def gitlabRepo = 'http://repository.vrpconsulting.com/roman.skaskevich/koshcheck-copy.git'
deleteDir()
dir('koshcheck-copy') {
    stage 'Fetch'
    def curdir = pwd()
    echo curdir
    git url: "${gitlabRepo}", branch: 'master'

    stage 'Archive'
    zip archive: true, dir: './src', glob: '', zipFile: 'src.zip'
    def savedZip = archive 'src.zip'
    echo savedZip

    stage 'Notify'
    emailext (
        to: 'roman.skaskevich@gmail.com',
        subject: "ZIP",
        body: "Attached zip must be there",
        attachmentsPattern: 'src.zip'
    )
}
```

I don't know if project archived successfully, but it isn't sent via email.

**EDIT #1**

Problem lay in that archive wasn't created. So I perform command which runs local 7zip for create archive: `bat "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\" a -tzip src.zip src"`.

Now remain the problem with sending this archive via email. Because job finished successfully, but returned:

> Sending email to: roman.skaskevich@gmail.com
>
> Error sending to the following VALID addresses: roman.skaskevich@gmail.com

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191040/jenkins-ext-email-plugin-fails-to-send-email-on-build-success) in which suggests, that attachment is too large. But I decrease size of archive from 7MB to 250kB and have the same problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That all looks valid and looks like it should work.
but zip archive: true and archive 'src.zip' do the same thing so kinda pointless doing both

Comment: If I right, command `archive` stores archive in the `archive` folder inside the `build` folder. But I see that there is no `archive` folder. So maybe problem lies in the storing file in my filesystem?

Comment: Actually just a thought try attachmentsPattern: '**/src.zip'

Comment: OK, I will try it!

Comment: I tried it, but now I see that problem lies in the zipping of the project and saving this zip for further use.

Comment: I have a feeling that a number of paths are workspace relative not working directory relative dir('koshcheck-copy') { may be what is breaking it

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly what did you mean. I solved this problem by the hardcoding. But it's the temporary solution. See EDIT #1.