# Jenkins: Can't fetch project's source code from GitLab

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, gitlab

I run my Jenkins server on the local machine, and I met problem with fetching project from GitLab repository. I don't know exactly what I have to done.

> ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
>
> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress http://repository.vrpconsulting.com/roman.skaskevich/koshcheck-copy.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
>
> stdout:
>
> stderr: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
>
> remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
>
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://repository.vrpconsulting.com/roman.skaskevich/koshcheck-copy.git/'

*GITLAB SETTINGS:* [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT3id.png)

**EDIT #1**

When I run `git fetch --tags --progress http://repository.vrpconsulting.com/roman.skaskevich/koshcheck-copy.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` on local machine, it performs successfully and dialog for entering login/password is showed.

But what I have to do that jenkins job performed this command successfully?

**EDIT #2**

For now, [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) helps me implements to checking credentials in Jenkinsfile.

**EDIT #3**

I run Jenkins server on another machine and have the same problem. I don't want to use login/password, so adding SSH key solved this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your repo is private. Private git repos requires authentication. Reconfigure your git client plugin check if you are able to connect to remote repo via password based authentication , if not , try SSHing to the repo.

Comment: Yes, but how can I do it in the Pipeline Item?

Comment: Make sure you have gitlab API and gitlab authentication plugin installed on Jenkins. Then go to the **job config**  -> Source code management . You should see a credentials dropdown. Add the Gitlab API token in the popup titled "Jenkins Credentials Provider: Jenkins" .

Comment: Yes, but for me, the problem was in using this credentials in the Pipeline Item. Now I use [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this ins private repo if you want to clone that repo to jenkins workspace you need to provide your gitlab credentials in jenins.

for that, you need to install jenkins plugin called "Gitlab Authentication plugin". once you completed the installation please do a restart.

Add Gitlab credentials in "Jenkins Credentials Provider: Jenkins".

later you can add your gitlab credentials in Source Code Management

[Source Code Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdO6p.png)

in credentials select the saved gitlab credentials.

Comment: But if I want to use Pipeline Item? Because I needed to [archive project and send it further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114227/jenkins-cant-send-zip-archive-via-email).

Comment: For now I done it by performing `git config --global --set credential.helper`.

Comment: if you added your credentials in jenkins configuration then no need to set credentials in git cache.

Comment: Yes, but for me, the problem was in using this credentials in the Pipeline Item. Now I use [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

Install plugins:
Gitlab
Gitlab authentication

Configure global credentials in jenkins:

go to credentials >> system >> global creds >> username & password

ID: git
username: your gitlab username
password: your gitlab password

Pipeline:

stage('SCM') {
            steps {
                git credentialsId: 'git', url: 'your gitlab url'
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too. In my case, the git repo is a private one.

I added the git link and then supplied the git credentials to the particular Jenkins job. The issue is gone and able to build project from Jenkins.