# Jenkins Editable Email Notification is not sending emails when the build status is passd but sends when build is failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

based on https://nozaki.me/roller/kyle/entry/articles-jenkins-email, in a Free style Jenkins Project, I configured a job to send emails even when the build is pass.

However, it only got triggered only when build is failed .
For the build pass instances, the output is as per below and not sending an email.

```
Started by user De Silva, Sameera
Running as SYSTEM
BigPanda Notifier: Success
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on slave_1 in workspace /opt/software/jenkins/workspace/SNOW_Automation/mvnpath
No emails were triggered.
[mvnpath] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins1851354422188041636.sh
+ echo sameera
sameera
BigPanda Notifier: Success
Email was triggered for: Always
Sending email for trigger: Always
Sending email to: sam@org.com
Not sent to the following valid addresses: sam@org.com
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Here are the screenshots of post-build action.

[image]

[image]

Here is the screenshot of Post build trigger.

[image]

Kindly help.

Comment: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-61242 - can you try if this is helpful. It seems like there might be a bug in the plugin so you will need to delete the project configuration and add again **after** the post action has been already set to Always.

Comment: Thank you , Pamela tried that but no avail.

Comment: did you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191040/jenkins-ext-email-plugin-fails-to-send-email-on-build-success?rq=1

Comment: Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System, and under the Extended E-mail Notification section enable the `Enable Debug Mode` option (check the checkbox). The plugin will now print detailed information on why the mail was not sent, which should help you understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was , by giving an email to Project From.

Project From: From whom

This field contains the sender's email address for the email notification. It is the "From" address that recipients will see.

I gave the rest of the fields as

Project From: myfrom@example.com
Project Recipient List: myrecepient@gmail.com
Project Reply-To List: (optional, if you want replies to go to a different address)

[image]